# How can I get the best video (with audio) in MP4 format?

Tags: download, youtube, youtube-dl, youtube-api

I am trying to download the best video and audio from the streaming url using youtube dl command line and below is the response. Knowing this, how can I get the best video (with audio) in MP4 format?

```
hls-audio-0-en__Main_-0                      mp4        audio only [en]
hls-audio-0-en__Main_-1                      mp4        audio only [en]
dash-6f83f6b4-5475-475f-8955-b2aca8bd9b54-0  m4a        audio only [en] DASH audio   96k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2 (48000Hz)
dash-6f83f6b4-5475-475f-8955-b2aca8bd9b54-1  m4a        audio only [en] DASH audio   96k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2 (48000Hz)
dash-b90bf8a1-4681-438b-80f9-17ccbfd52366-0  mp4        480x270    DASH video   96k , mp4_dash container, avc1.420015, video only
dash-b90bf8a1-4681-438b-80f9-17ccbfd52366-1  mp4        480x270    DASH video   96k , mp4_dash container, avc1.420015, video only
dash-bc267a90-3ac3-4eed-a4b9-73bd6b94bec7-0  mp4        480x270    DASH video  149k , mp4_dash container, avc1.420015, video only
dash-bc267a90-3ac3-4eed-a4b9-73bd6b94bec7-1  mp4        480x270    DASH video  149k , mp4_dash container, avc1.420015, video only
hls-211-0                                    mp4        480x270     211k , avc1.420015, video only
hls-211-1                                    mp4        480x270     211k , avc1.420015, video only
hls-269-0                                    mp4        480x270     269k , avc1.420015, video only
hls-269-1                                    mp4        480x270     269k , avc1.420015, video only
dash-da90237b-f0a3-4f51-8962-d41cb1d9babe-0  mp4        640x360    DASH video  298k , mp4_dash container, avc1.42001e, video only
dash-da90237b-f0a3-4f51-8962-d41cb1d9babe-1  mp4        640x360    DASH video  298k , mp4_dash container, avc1.42001e, video only
hls-433-0                                    mp4        640x360     433k , avc1.42001e, video only
hls-433-1                                    mp4        640x360     433k , avc1.42001e, video only
dash-fcf57c07-c6e3-4761-8793-d2722f438deb-0  mp4        480x270    DASH video  449k , mp4_dash container, avc1.420015, video only
dash-fcf57c07-c6e3-4761-8793-d2722f438deb-1  mp4        480x270    DASH video  449k , mp4_dash container, avc1.420015, video only
hls-599-0                                    mp4        480x270     599k , avc1.420015, video only
hls-599-1                                    mp4        480x270     599k , avc1.420015, video only
dash-f1e7f24b-d987-42c0-a361-8aca5ed5b332-0  mp4        640x360    DASH video  600k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001e, video only
dash-f1e7f24b-d987-42c0-a361-8aca5ed5b332-1  mp4        640x360    DASH video  600k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001e, video only
hls-765-0                                    mp4        640x360     765k , avc1.4d001e, video only
hls-765-1                                    mp4        640x360     765k , avc1.4d001e, video only
dash-1374be5e-cf80-4070-908f-30072d7ac63c-0  mp4        960x540    DASH video  897k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001f, video only
dash-1374be5e-cf80-4070-908f-30072d7ac63c-1  mp4        960x540    DASH video  897k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001f, video only
dash-92c6d340-b465-4dac-8d90-b778ab129c3b-0  mp4        640x360    DASH video  902k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001e, video only
dash-92c6d340-b465-4dac-8d90-b778ab129c3b-1  mp4        640x360    DASH video  902k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001e, video only
hls-1092-0                                   mp4        960x540    1092k , avc1.4d001f, video only
hls-1092-1                                   mp4        960x540    1092k , avc1.4d001f, video only
hls-1097-0                                   mp4        640x360    1097k , avc1.4d001e, video only
hls-1097-1                                   mp4        640x360    1097k , avc1.4d001e, video only
dash-db8ce174-87d5-4a7c-ad82-339f0762ac13-0  mp4        1024x576   DASH video 1198k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001f, video only
dash-db8ce174-87d5-4a7c-ad82-339f0762ac13-1  mp4        1024x576   DASH video 1198k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001f, video only
hls-1423-0                                   mp4        1024x576   1423k , avc1.4d001f, video only
hls-1423-1                                   mp4        1024x576   1423k , avc1.4d001f, video only
dash-20e55c72-e12b-4b9c-9e6c-b0e2beb1b4dc-0  mp4        1280x720   DASH video 1501k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001f, video only
dash-20e55c72-e12b-4b9c-9e6c-b0e2beb1b4dc-1  mp4        1280x720   DASH video 1501k , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d001f, video only
hls-1756-0                                   mp4        1280x720   1756k , avc1.4d001f, video only
hls-1756-1                                   mp4        1280x720   1756k , avc1.4d001f, video only (best)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will choose the best video and audio qualities:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio youtube.com/watch?v=videocode
```

And then if the best video and audio streams aren't in the `mp4` format, you can also pass a `--recode-video mp4` option.

The output you showed in your question doesn't show any video formats other than `mp4` so you won't need to add that extra option in this case.

Comment: Great and Thanks.   I used the below mentioned syntax and its worked.                    
   youtube-dl.exe -f hls-1756-0+hls-audio-0-en__Main_-0 --recode-video mp4 <url>

Comment: @SatishKumar Glad to hear that! You can also just leave it as `bestvideo+bestaudio` and youtube-dl will *automatically* pick the best video and audio if you want to save a bit of time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) (it's youtube-dl fork) which has more options in selecting formats and post downloading options.
Also it's more up-to-date

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).